Detailed computation of Expect Mean Squares in ANOVA
I'm struggling with the computation of the EMS (Expected Mean Squares) in a mixed-effect ANOVA. I'm following the Hedeker-Gibbons book on Longitudinal Data Analysis. $y_{ij}$ is a continuous outcome, $\pi$ is a random effect and $\tau$ a fixed effect.
\begin{align}
y_{ij}           &= \mu + \pi_i + \tau_{j} + \varepsilon_{ij}  \\
\pi_{i}         &\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma_{\pi}^2)   \\
\varepsilon_{ij} &\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2) \\
\sum \tau_j &= 0
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
i = 1,\ldots,N \\
j = 1,\ldots,n
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
SS_{\pi} &= \sum_{ij} (y_{i\cdot} - y_{\cdot\cdot})^2 \\
 &= n \sum_i (\pi_i  -\pi_\cdot + \varepsilon_{i\cdot} - \varepsilon_{\cdot\cdot})^2 \\
SS_\pi &= n \sum (\pi_i - \pi_\cdot)^2 + n \sum (\varepsilon_{i\cdot}-\varepsilon_{\cdot\cdot})^2 \\
 E[SS_{\pi}] &= n(N-1) \sigma_{\pi}^2 + n(N-1) \sigma^2/n 
\end{align}
using the fact that $\varepsilon_{i\cdot} - \varepsilon_{\cdot\cdot} \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2 / n)$ from the CLT.
We then have $MS_\pi = SS_\pi / (N-1) = n \sigma_\pi^2 + \sigma^2$. All is fine so far.

Now, it is claimed that the expectation of $MS_R = \sum_{ij} (y_{ij} - y_{i\cdot} - y_{\cdot j} + y_{\cdot\cdot})^2$ is simply equal to $\sigma$.
But I fail to get this result and would like to know how to proceed.
\begin{align}
SS_R &= \sum_{ij} (y_{ij} - y_{i\cdot} - y_{\cdot j} + y_{\cdot\cdot})^2 \\
 &= \sum_{ij} (\varepsilon_{ij} - \varepsilon_{i\cdot} - \varepsilon_{\cdot j} + \varepsilon_{\cdot\cdot})^2
\end{align}
Here, I'm not quite sure how to deal with this formula and how to get an expectation of $(N-1)(n-1) \sigma^2$.

Ok, I found a trick for the computation.
I know that the expectation of $ SS = \sum_{ij} (\varepsilon_{ij} - \varepsilon_{\cdot\cdot})^2$  is $(nN-1) \sigma^2$.
I artificially introduce the averages over $i$ and $j$ in $SS$:
\begin{align}
SS = \sum_{ij} (\varepsilon_{ij} +(\varepsilon_{i\cdot} - \varepsilon_{i\cdot}) + (\varepsilon_{\cdot j} - \varepsilon_{\cdot j}) + (\varepsilon_{\cdot\cdot} - \varepsilon_{\cdot\cdot}) - \varepsilon_{\cdot\cdot})^2 
\end{align}
I split the sums (the cross-terms are all zero).
\begin{align}
SS = \sum_{ij} (\varepsilon_{ij} -\varepsilon_{i\cdot} - \varepsilon_{\cdot j} +\varepsilon_{\cdot\cdot})^2 + \sum_{ij} (\varepsilon_{\cdot j} - \varepsilon_{\cdot\cdot})^2 + \sum_{ij} (\varepsilon_{i\cdot} -\varepsilon_{\cdot\cdot})^2 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
(nN-1) \sigma^2 = E[SS_R] + (n-1) \sigma^2 + (N-1) \sigma^2 
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
E[SS_R] &= (nN-1 - n + 1 - N + 1) \sigma^2 \\
&= (n-1)(N-1) \sigma^2
\end{align}
Of course, there may be a straighter answer than this workaround and it would be helpful if somebody provided it.
